# Build a select from a json file in PHP or JS

Tags: javascript, php, json

How can I build a select with from a json file like this ?

```
{
    "AF": "Afghanistan",
    "AL": "Albania",
    "DZ": "Algeria",
    "AS": "American Samoa",
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to make something like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="AL">Albania</option>
</select>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Javascript, you should use Ajax for get a JSON data. Then suppose we already have the data "JSON", You can use loops to work with it, eg:

```js
var json_data = {
    "AF": "Afghanistan",
    "AL": "Albania",
    "DZ": "Algeria",
    "AS": "American Samoa"
};

var select = document.querySelector("#mySelect");

for(var countryCode in json_data){
   var option = new Option(json_data[countryCode], countryCode);
   select.appendChild(option);
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect"></select>
```

### Using jQuery:

jQuery simplifies your work, and you have the [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) method to get JSON data from a file, and [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) for working with objects

```js
$.getJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tarraq/JSON-data-arrays/master/countries/english/countries-key-value.json", function(jsonData){
   var select = $("#mySelect");
   $.each(jsonData, function(key, country){
      select.append($("<option>", {value: key, text: country}))
   })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="mySelect"></select>
```

Comment: wasn't knowing about `querySelector`, +1

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick in PHP. Takes the JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP array. Than iterate over the array to make all select options.

```
<?php

$json = '{
    "AF": "Afghanistan",
    "AL": "Albania",
    "DZ": "Algeria",
    "AS": "American Samoa"
}';

$decoded = json_decode($json, true)
?>

</select>   
    <?  foreach($decoded as $key => $value){?>

        <option value="<? echo $key; ?>"><? echo $value; ?></option>

    <?  }   ?>

<select>
```

Comment: Don't use short tags in answers, they might not be enabled on the user's system.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myJason = {"AF": "Afghanistan","AL": "Albania","DZ": "Algeria","AS": "American Samoa"}



$.each(myJson,function(key,val) {
$('#mySelect').append('<option value="'+ key + '">' + val + '</option>');
});
```